# MVC Repository pattern and adding records to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to insert comment records for a Blog feature I am slowly developing in order to grasp the MVC framework within .NET. I get repository pattern is not .NET. Its coming along ok. I am having a little difficulty wiring it all up so that I can successfully insert comments into my database.

Here is the Inherited class which also uses IDisposable. Don't really know what for. Probably garbage collection and  possibly multiple inheritance employed.

```
 public class BlogRepository : IBlogRepository, IDisposable
{
    private BlogDataDataContext _dataContext;

    public BlogRepository() { _dataContext = new BlogDataDataContext(); }

   // #region IBlogRepository Members

    public IList<Entry> Posts()
    {
        var entries = from m in _dataContext.Entries select m;
        return entries.ToList();
    }

    public void InsertComment(Comment comment)
    {
        _dataContext.Comments.InsertOnSubmit(comment);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _dataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _dataContext.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }




   // #endregion
}
```

I believe all above is implemented ok. The problem I have is the next bit. Here is the controller with overloaded BlogPost using GET and POST for differing tasks. Im interested in the second method the post.

```
public ActionResult BlogPost(int id, string title){
        var viewModel = new ListViewModel(_repository);            
        ViewData["id"] = id;
        return View("BlogPost", viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BlogPost(int id, string username, string email, string message)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid) {

        // help....

            return RedirectToAction("BlogPost");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Here is the model I am using which is bound to the View.

```
 public class ListViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " A Name is required *")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [StringLength(160, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 2 & 160 characters in length.")]
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email address required *")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [StringLength(160, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 2 & 160 characters in length *")]
    [EmailValidation(ErrorMessage = "Must be valid email *")]
    public string AuthorEmail { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " A Message is required *")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [StringLength(4000, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 2 & 4000 characters in length *")]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public ListViewModel(IBlogRepository blogRepository)
    {
        Posts = blogRepository.Posts();
    }

    public IList<Entry> Posts { get; private set; }
    public IList<Comment> Comment { get; private set; }
}
```

I dont know how to wire up the BlogPost POST method to the above ListViewModel which has some validation rules so that I can successfully insert data into my database and keep the integrity of the Repository pattern. I am having difficulty because I can only use one Model. If anyone can give me any insight into where I am going slightly wrong I would very thankful. I know I'm close and once achieved I can apply this approach to all my future work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your action to accept the model as the parameter e.g.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult BlogPost(ListViewModel model)
    {

    }
```

UPDATE:

Remove the constructor from ListViewModel so it now looks like

```
public class ListViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = " A Name is required *")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [StringLength(160, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 2 & 160 characters in length.")]
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email address required *")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [StringLength(160, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 2 & 160 characters in length *")]
    [EmailValidation(ErrorMessage = "Must be valid email *")]
    public string AuthorEmail { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = " A Message is required *")]
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [StringLength(4000, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 2 & 4000 characters in length *")]
    public string Body { get; set; }


    public IList<Entry> Posts { get; private set; }
    public IList<Comment> Comment { get; private set; }
}
```

Then in your controller add the repository there something like

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult BlogPost(int id, string username, string email, string message)
        {
var repo = new BlogRepository();

            if (ModelState.IsValid) {

            // help....

                return RedirectToAction("BlogPost");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: I get a No parameterless constructor defined for this object exception.

Comment: What does your view code look like? You will need to have a form on it with inputs for the various properties of the ListViewModel

Comment: Oh no sorry you don't have a parameterless constructor for ListViewModel. Does the view model need to have a property for the repository? It should not if you follow the MVC design pattern. Your controller should have the repository not the View.

Comment: My View has the controls that are in the Model. I will give this a good go. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think your implementation of the repository pattern is slightly wrong, take a look at this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Then for your question, I think your blog and comment model should look like:

```
public class BlogPost
{
  // properties such as id, title, body, etc. Don't forget to add validation attributes.

  public virtual IList<Comment> Comments {get;set;}
}

public class Comment
{
  // again properties such as id, author, e-mail, etc. and validation

  // the FK to BlogPost
  public int BlogPostId {get;set;}
  public virtual BlogPost BlogPost {get;set;}
}
```

For both entities you should make a repository as explained in that tutorial. The in MVC:

```
public ActionResult AddComment(int blogPostId)
{
  return View(new Comment { BlogPostId = blogPostId} ); // maybe some validating on the blogPostId
}

[HttpPost]
public ACtionResult AddComment(Comment model)
{
  // do some manual validating yourself first, e.g. check if the model.BlogPostId still exists. One could have changed this to test your security...

  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    // save the new comment here, for examle:
    var commentRepo = new CommentRepository();
    commentRepo.Insert(model);
    commentRepo.Save();

    return Redirect.... // redirect to for example the post page
  }
  return View(model);
}
```